# Size of Regression Coefficients

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, probit

I have run a probit regression and the size of my coefficients seem to be quite big with respect to other similar studies.  For example, 0.254 vs 1.207 - does this mean anything in particular or is it all just relative to your model etc.?

Comment: Unless the set of coefficients in each regression model are identical, the interpretation of the two coefficients are different.

Comment: I am more trying to analyse whether this means that my model is a 'worse' fit or if large coefficients in general mean anything in particular

Comment: I think TrynnaDoStat meant 'variables' in place of the first 'coefficients.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Probit (and Logit) model the interesting factor is (often):

$$
\Delta \hat{P} (y=1|\boldsymbol{x}) \approx [g(\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\boldsymbol{x}]\Delta x_j
$$

This means that in Probit (Logit) model, the average/partial effect cannot be traced out directly from the estimate of some $\beta_j$. One can show that only the sign (+/-), of the estiamte does not change - however, the effect does change - depending on "where" (how large or small) the other $\boldsymbol{x_j}$ are.

So to answer your question, you cannot conclude as you do - it is littearly relative. Unless, as TrynnaDoStat says, you include excatly the same variables.

Comment: Thanks @Repmat.  I have now run another probit model for different but (similar) sets of data and I am getting tiny coefficient sizes (x10^-17) for one - does this similarly mean anything?

Comment: Most likely a feature of the sample, since I have no idea what you are modeling it is hard to say. You could compare summary statistics of your data and the data from the paper